# Unable to install AppFabric for windows server

Tags: sharepoint-2013, appfabric, prerequisites

I have installed all the prerequisites for installing SharePoint 2013 but during installation of AppFabric for windows server, it is showing an error as "The tool was unable to install Windows Server AppFabric".
I tried using Microsoft web platform Installer and it gets installed successfully  installed but when i again run the prerequisites for SharePoint 2013, same error is thrown and prerequisites installation stopped.
I also tried to install it offline by downloading the setup of AppFabric for windows server through Microsoft site but no luck....

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: On which operation system you are trying to install it? Windows Server 2012?

Comment: hi, Yevgeniy, thanks for reply.yes i was trying it on Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after reading the log file
i found this command which i manually executed in command prompt with some modifications and its done!!!

Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\338f6462408072c851cf3b1e\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-

64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-03-05

18-06-39).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-03-05 18-06-39).log"

INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US

Then remove the words Process.Start: and /quiet and execute the command as administrator in MSDOS

C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /norestart /i "c:\338f6462408072c851cf3b1e\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi"

ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2013-03-05 18-06-

39).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2013-03-05 18-06-39).log" INSTALLDIR="C:

\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US

Answer (score 1):

It is usually possible to install Sharepoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2 that does not support the prerequisites of tool by performing the following steps:

1. Install from an **elevated Windows command prompt** the "WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe" command with the path where the executable:

   WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64 /i CacheClient,CachingService,CacheAdmin /gac
2. Then install "AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU" the same way

   AppFabric1.1-RTM-KB2671763-x64-ENU.exe
3. Reboot the Server

Answer (score 1):

It took me two good days finding the solution. And all my search did not work until when one blog gave me some useful information,

> The installer is trying to run the executable C:\Windows\System32\ServerManagerCMD.exe

```
2014-09-03 23:45:23 - "C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe" -inputpath "somepath"
```

Taking a look in the `system32` directory, you'll see that in R2, `ServerManagerCMD.exe` doesn't exist!

How do we fix that?

We do the logical thing: Take `ServerManager.exe`, copy it, and rename it to `ServerManagerCMD.exe`. Who cares if it's messy if it works. Case in point:

Credit goes to [this blog post of "SomeShinyObject"](http://www.someshinyobject.com/posts/server-2012-r2-and-sharepoint-2013-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web).

Answer (score 0):

Another Simple resolution to this problem is -

Check for Windows update service. (windows+r and type services.msc)
If this service is stopped then start the service manually.

This service needs to be in running mode.
AppFabric installation also goes in error due to this service not in running mode

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Solution 1:

1. Run pre-requisite first before installing SharePoint 2013
2. Uninstall App fabric if installed. Also start the windows update feature if not ON.
3. Copy latest downloaded copy of Appfabric to the **`prerequisiteinstallerfiles`** folder.
4. Run the Pre-requisite installer again and restart the system.
5. It will start ShapePoint2013 installation automatically.

Solution 2:

1. Go to System properties -> Environment variables
2. Append the following path to **`PSModulePath`** entry in System variable - `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` using `;`
   It should look like this:
   **`C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules`**
3. Now follow the Solution 1.